Build fail with an exception Execution failed for task ':fluttertoast:compileDebugKotlin'
I tried
flutter pub cache repair
flutter pub get
flutter pub upgrade
still not able to resolve

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':fluttertoast:compileDebugKotlin'.


A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerRunnerWithWorkers$GradleKotlinCompilerWorkAction
Compilation error. See log for more details


This question is similar to: What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':fluttertoast:compileDebugKotlin'. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
